# Simple tool to monitor HAProxy web requests?

Tags: monitoring, haproxy, monit

I'm looking for a tool that can monitor the number of requests that are going to the nodes within HAProxy to determine the need to push out another node to loadbalance the requests. Can something like monit/nagios do this? What are some other simple tools?

Answer (score 1):

Quoting the [docs](https://cbonte.github.io/haproxy-dconv/configuration-1.5.html#9):

> It is possible to query HAProxy about its status. The most commonly used
>   mechanism is the HTTP statistics page. This page also exposes an alternative
>   CSV output format for monitoring tools. The same format is provided on the
>   Unix socket.

Additionally, you could have a look at [HAtop](http://feurix.org/projects/hatop/), which is

> an interactive ncurses client and real-time monitoring, statistics displaying tool [...].

Answer (score 1):

HAtop will in fact help you to get the information, but if you somehow want to react and get an email or doing a custom application look for monitoring solutions like Pandora FMS, Zabbix, PRTG for naming a few.

In Japan Pandora FMS is very extended, so that is the one I learned and use for both home and professional cases. Check them out here if you like: http://pandorafms.com/monitoring-solutions/server-monitoring/

Comment: Isn't Nagios and Monit a good script execution monitoring solution as well?